# knockout.js custom binding callback executes after a non-dependent observable is updated

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events

I have this weird issue where if I update my `quantity` observable through a callback `updateQuantity` on my custom binding `checkbox` it calls my `update` function on my custom binding.  My element with the custom binding doesnt, or shouldnt have any type of subscription to it, but it gets executed again.  This calls my callback method twice.  Am I missing something there?  If my `updateQuantity` only has a `return true`, then it doesn't call the `update` function.  Also if I remove `values.callback($element.is(':checked') || checked);` in my `update` method of the `custom binding` it also works.  It's like that line causes a subscription or something.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkbox: { text: 'Hello', callback: updateQuantity.bind($data) }" />
```

**Callback method**

```
 self.quantity = ko.observable(0);

self.updateQuantity = function (checked) {
            var quantity = self.quantity();
            if (checked)
                self.quantity(quantity + 1);
            else if ((quantity - 1) >= 0) {
                self.quantity(quantity - 1);
            }
            return false;
        };
```

**Custom Binding**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.checkbox = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

            var values = valueAccessor();
            var checked = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(values.checked);
            var css = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(values.css);
            var $element = $(element);

            var button = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-check ' + (values.buttonClass || '') + '" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox"><i class="' + (values.iconClass || 'icon-ok') + '"></i> ' + (values.text || '') + '</button>');

            button.click(function (evt, data) {

                if (typeof (values.callback) != 'undefined') {
                    values.callback($(element).is(':checked') || checked);
                }

                return true;
            });

            button.insertBefore(element);
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

            var values = valueAccessor();
            var checked = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(values.checked);

            if (typeof(values.callback) != 'undefined') {
                values.callback($(element).is(':checked') || checked);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used .peek() in the standalone callback method and it worked.  Still not sure why it would re-evaluate the custom binding though on a regular retrieval.

```
 var quantity = self.quantity.peek();
```